# A basis for topology of $\mathbb R^2$

Tags: general-topology

I'm studying via John Lee's book on general toplogy and i've came across this question, but it doesn't makes any sense to me, unless the following basis is a basis for product topology:

[image: Question 2.5]

But is there any other topology that could be generated?

Comment: It can't, you're right. A basis for a topology on $\mathbb R^2$ must be a collection of subsets of $\mathbb R^2$. Assume he means the product topology.

Comment: It seems basis elements are vertical line segments  in $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: @DavidMitra  did not noticed this, so it would make sense as a regular basis right?

Comment: "regular"? It does generate a  toplogy on $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: @DavidMitra regular in the sense that there is no problem with it hahaha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not a basis for the product topology, or indeed any other topology you're familiar with on the plane. The sets in $\mathcal{B}$ are vertical line segments, while the usual basis for the product topology would be open rectangles - and the product topology is the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Now for those identity maps, we're comparing this to the usual topology. If a set is open relative to $\mathcal{B}$, is it open in the usual topology? If a set is open in the usual topology, is it open relative to $\mathcal{B}$?

Comment: I was indeed thinking about using that $f$ is continuous if a topology is contained in another, but i just can't compare it

Comment: My guess is that lines could app up to boxes, or even open balls, but the other way just doesn't works

Comment: Yes, exactly. A set in $\mathcal(B)$ is not open in the usual topology, while an open box is a union of open vertical segments - so the usual topology is contained in this one.

Answer (score 1):

This is essentially the product topology of $\mathbb{R}$ in the discrete topology in the first factor, and the usual topology in the second. So it's clearly strictly finer than the usual (=product) topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$, so that the identity is only continuous with the usual topology as co-domain.